# Default Request Header does not accept any value its always null

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am doing an web api integration test.

I want to pass my bearer token to the header of a Http Request:

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "eJ43k5l435j34l5j43l5j34l5jl35j34l5j344l.4534535.534534sample...");
```

When this line of code is done I look into the `httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization` property and it is NULL ?

Why this?

**UPDATE**

This is from the base class of my integration test class:

```
 protected HttpClient Client { get { return server.HttpClient; } }
```

When I manually new up a http client in the test class:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("key","value");
```

it works but not with my Client !?

**UPDATE 2**

OK I found this out:

```
 var c = Client;
 c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("bla", "bla");
```

IT WORKS, but why do I have to read my client in a new variable?

Comment: I think I need a bit more code to solve this.. where is `httpClient` in your first line coming from? As I see it, this is a HttpClient object, is that a new object from `protected HttpClient Client { get { return server.HttpClient; } }` ?? Ifso, what is all done with `server`. And are you using this code on an API, or a application USING an API?

Comment: Could you add some information about the type of your server variable? If it is a class you created or a framework type. In case it is a class of your own, could you give more information about how HttpClient is being instantiated?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have exactly the same problem, trying to run integration tests on a WebAPI2 codebase, and I assign the header (as you do) and immediately on the next line it is ALWAYS null... this has been driving me mad. Instead of setting the header on the HttpClient, I found a (single) example where the programmer set the header on the HttpMessageRequest instead, and sent that using HttpClient.SendAsync, rather than HttpClient.PostAsJson for example... this cost me a lot of time and I still don't know why the header can't be set on the HttpClient??

Answer (score 0):

I've read (in an article that I cannot find, sorry) that the Auth headers on the HttpClient(especially in the inmemory TestServer host, which apparently cannot handle authenticated services and so seems to be kind of useless to me? see https://blog.kloud.com.au/2014/10/26/asp-net-web-api-integration-testing-with-one-line-of-code/ "Unfortunately, in-memory solution doesn’t work for me out of the box. Seems like it can’t handle authentication. I use UseJwtBearerAuthentication (JWT bearer token middleware) and my api calls result in 401") in webapi are GET only - i had the same problem, trying to do integration tests against authenticated endpoints - i got my bearer token, added it to the header, but in the next line of code, it was NULL.

The advice I found (and the solution i got working) was to add the Bearer header to the HttpRequestMessage headers, NOT the HttpClient headers, and then use HttpClient.SendAsync rather than HttpClient.PostAsync (which apparently, for whatever reason, posts body content but NOT headers).

I have already wasted so much time trying to figure this out, and most of the tutorials you find do NOT deal with auth headers, so I'm surprised more people dont discuss this problem (assuming of course, that I'm not just a muppet). But yeah, try adding your auth headers to the request message, not the http client.

Answer (score 0):

7 years later, I had the same issue with a WPF app using .NET Core 6 and a Singleton implementation that was similar to the context you described.

Switching for the Lazy implementation of Singleton fixed the issue of the header not correctly adding to the existing instance of HttpClient.

```
public sealed class HttpService
{
    private HttpService() { }

    private static readonly Lazy<HttpClient> lazy = new Lazy<HttpClient>(
        () => {
            string token = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["access_token"];

            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            
            return client; 
        });

    public static HttpClient Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return lazy.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

The value of the access_token setting from my App.config does not start with "Bearer ", it contains only the token string.

For more about the various Singleton possible implementations:

https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Singleton